# Как запустить все методы класса одновременно?

Tags: java, многопоточность

К чему все это? У меня класс, который должен много раз выполнять три метода, методы выполняются поочередно, думаю если запустить их все одновременно, то это должно добавить к скорости выполнения программы ибо ужасно медленно работает.(все методы одного класса, каждый метод отдельно в своем потоке)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
    ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        new Thread(exampleClass::method1).start();
        new Thread(exampleClass::method2).start();
        new Thread(exampleClass::method3).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант предложенный @Михаил Кетов не плох. Но в нем есть один нюанс, создания потоков это **не моментальная операция**. Она требует времени и в момент когда будет создаваться поток для следующего метода, другой уже может выполнить свою работу.

Если хотите добиться **действительного одновременного выполнения**, то следует использовать `java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`.

```
private static class Together {
    private final CyclicBarrier barrier;

    private Together(int threadCount) {
        this.barrier = new CyclicBarrier(threadCount);
    }

    private void invoke(Runnable action) {
        new Thread(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        barrier.await();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    action.run();
                }).start();
    }
}
```

И выполнять операции следующим образом:

```
Together together = new Together(3);
together.invoke(object::method1);
together.invoke(object::method2);
together.invoke(object::method3);
```

Что здесь происходит? Когда поток создан, он не продолжает выполнение, а блокируется на `barrier`, и ждет когда все потоки (в данном случаи их 3) проинициализируются. И только когда последний поток, вызывает метод `await()` все они просыпаются и **одновременно** продолжают выполняться

Comment: предложенный пример очень интересен, но я исхожу с точки зрения быстродействия кода и пока не понятно, что будет быстрее работать (если вообще даст хоть какое либо ускорение). Мне не особо важно одновременно сработают или нет главное чтобы быстро